# How do you determine which file is imported in Python with an "import" statement?

Tags: python, import

How do you determine which file is imported in Python with an "import" statement?

I want to determine that I am loading the correct version of a locally modified .py file.  Basically the equivalent of "which" in a POSIX environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start python with the `-v` parameter to enable debugging output. When you then import a module, Python will print out where the module was imported from:

```
$ python -v
...
>>> import re
# /usr/lib/python2.6/re.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/re.py
import re # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/re.pyc
...
```

If you additionally want to see in what other places Python searched for the module, add a second `-v`:

```
$ python -v -v
...
>>> import re
# trying re.so
# trying remodule.so
# trying re.py
# trying re.pyc
# trying /usr/lib/python2.6/re.so
# trying /usr/lib/python2.6/remodule.so
# trying /usr/lib/python2.6/re.py
# /usr/lib/python2.6/re.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/re.py
import re # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/re.pyc
...
```

Answer (score 12):

Look at its `__file__` attribute.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the easiest method.
import module
print module.__file__

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  Imported modules have a `__file__` field that is the file that was loaded.  Combine that with `__import__`, I defined a function:

`which = lambda str : __import__(str).__file__`.

Comment: When you immediately assign a lambda to a variable, you should just use a def statement: `def which(str): return __import__(str).__file__`.

Answer (score 0):

Put an explicit version identifier in each module.

```
__version__ = "Some.version.String"
```

Put these in every module you write, without exception.

```
import someModule
print someModule.__version__
```

This is (a) explicit, (b) easy to manage.  You can also use "Keyword Substitution" from your version control tool to actually fill in the version string for you on each commit.