# How to just import part of __init__.py?

Tags: python

I have a package with some files and I'm having some importation issues.
Let's say I have the following files:

```
main.py
Lib
 ├─ __init__.py
 ├─ file1.py
 └─ file2.py
```

**main.py**:

```
from Lib import ClassA

foo = ClassA('anything')
```

**Lib/init.py**:

```
from .file1 import ClassA
from .file2 import ClassB
```

**file1.py**:

```
import a_lot_of_things

class ClassA:
  pass
```

**file2.py**:

```
import a_lot_of_other_things

class ClassB:
  pass
```

This code works, but Python will also import all the other classes in the file, as the ClassB. The problem is that Python takes a lot of time importing all the libraries of file2.py which I don't wanna use.

I know it happens because Python is running init.py and it is importing all classes, even if I ask for just one. But I think it should do this only if I write:

```
from Lib import *
```

Is there a way to, inside init.py, check if I'm importing all or just one specific class to run just this file/importation?

I also tried to structure my directory this way:

```
main.py
Lib
 ├─ __init__.py
 ├─ ClassA
 │   ├─ __init__.py
 │   └─ file1.py
 └─ ClassB 
     ├─ __init__.py
     └─ file2.py
```

So I cleaned Lib/init.py and put the importations into each init.py.

**ClassA/init.py**:

```
from .file1 import ClassA
```

**ClassB/init.py**:

```
from .file2 import ClassB
```

But now I need to use it this way:

**main.py**:

```
from Lib import ClassA

foo = ClassA.ClassA('anything')
```

And I'd like to use it directly, as I wrote before. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542809/how-do-you-determine-which-file-is-imported-in-python-with-an-import-statement

Comment: @PravinRGMishra how is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

If you import a module (or import something from within a module) everything that that module imports will also be imported.

You can only avoid this by placing imports within a local context

For example

```
my_module:

import some_stuff

def do_stuff()
    pass

def do_some_specific_things()
    import some_specific_stuff_only_relevant_to_this_function
    pass
```

If you now call `from my_module import do_stuff` then `import some_stuff` will be executed, but `import some_specific_stuff_only_relevant_to_this_function` will not.

By the way, structuring your code as follows does not make sense:

```
main.py
Lib
 ├─ __init__.py
 ├─ ClassA
 │   ├─ __init__.py
 │   └─ file1.py
 └─ ClassB 
     ├─ __init__.py
     └─ file2.py
```

A class is within a module(`file1` and `file2` are modules). A module cannot sit within a class.